# Parse all text files in a directory using Python 2.7 and re module

Tags: regex, python-2.7

I have created a script, using the re module in Python 2.7,  that parses data out of a text file. I have about 300 text files in a directory (Directory ALL in the same folder as the python script) and wish to have my script parse the data out of each text file in that directory (Please note that the directory only has text files).

```
import re

f = open ("All/text1.txt", "rb")
readfile = f.read()

ID1 = re.findall(r"ID1:(.*?)ID2", readfile, re.DOTALL)
ID1 = ID1[0]

print ID1
```

What I want to do is have that script run on all the text files in the directory printing out the ID1 of each file. I am not really certain how to do this. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do the file contents look like? What is the context of the IDs? What characters can ID consist of?

Comment: You probably want to look at `os.walk` if there are subdirectories or `os.listdir`.  Those will let you get all the files in a directory, then you could loop over them and do your matching

Comment: The IDs come in different formats and varieties. Its diffcult to say. Thats whay i wanted the text that is in between text.

Comment: @ Eric Renouf... os.listdir did it. Thanks